# How should we configure Config link on custom module?

Tags: forms, 9, configuration

[image]

I need to create Config link while enabling module. In routing file, I have mention the path name of config form, but its not directly show in the Configuration page. Below is my routing code.

```
dm_user_timezone.user_timezone_settings:
path: '/admin/config/usertimezone/usertimezoneconfig'
defaults:
 _form: '\Drupal\dm_user_timezone\Form\UserTimezoneSettingForm'
 _title: 'User timezone page configuration'
requirements:
 _permission: 'access administration pages'
options:
 _admin_route: TRUE
```

My folder sructure looks like this. Need help what I missed here.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add `configure: dm_user_timezone.user_timezone_settings` to the `dm_user_timezone.info.yml` file. The `configure` option is [documented on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-modules/let-drupal-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file).

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works. :) One more question here, How should I display my module link on Configuration (/admin/config) page like People->Account Settings?

Comment: @latikas - Find a contrib module that does the same and then follow its sample.

Comment: @latikas That is a different question that should be asked as new question. Comments should be used when there is anything not clear in the given answer, not to ask unrelated questions.